# How do you make object placement realistic when there's a delay finding planes using ARCore?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

There's a bit of a delay when detecting planes using ARCore. That's fine, but what do you do when you want to place an object on a plane as the user pans the phone?

With the delay, the object pops into the screen after the plane is detected, rather than appearing as panned, which isn't realistic.

Answer (score 2):

### *Let's compare two leading AR SDKs*

### LiDAR scanner in iOS devices for ARKit 4.0

Since an official release of ARKit 3.5 there's a support for brand-new `Light Detection And Ranging` scanner allowing considerably reduce a time required for detecting a vertical and/or horizontal planes (it operates at nano-second speed). Apple has implemented this sensor on the rear camera of iPad Pro 2020. LiDAR scanner (that is basically `direct ToF`) gives us almost instant polygonal mesh of real-world environment in AR app, which is suitable for People/Objects Occlusion feature, precise ZDepth-object-placement and a complex collision shape for dynamics. A working distance of Apple LiDAR scanner is up to 5 meters. LiDAR scanner helps you detect planes in poorly-lit rooms with no feature points on walls and a floor.

### iToF cameras in Android Devices for ARCore 1.18

3D `indirect Time-of-Flight` sensor is a sort of scannerless LiDAR. It also surveys the surrounding environment and accurately measures a distance. Although LiDARs and iToFs at their core are almost the same things, a scanner type is more accurate since it uses multiple laser pulses versus just one large flash laser pulse. In Android world, Huawei and Samsung, for instance, include scannerless 3D iToF sensors in their smartphones. Google Pixel 4 doesn't have iToF camera. A working distance of iToF sensor is up to 5 meters and more. Let's see what Google says about its brand-new Depth API:

> Google's `Depth API` uses a depth-from-motion algorithm to create depth maps, which you can obtain using `acquireDepthImage()` method. This algorithm takes multiple device images from different angles and compares them to estimate the distance to every pixel as a user moves their phone. If the device has an active depth sensor, such as a time-of-flight sensor (or iToF sensor), that data is automatically included in the processed depth. This enhances the existing depth map and enables depth even when the camera is not moving. It also provides better depth on surfaces with few or no features, such as white walls, or in dynamic scenes with moving people or objects.

### Recommendations

When you're using AR app built on ARCore without iToF sensor support, you need to detect planes in a well-lit environment containing a rich and unique wall and floor textures (you needn't track repetitive textures or textures like "polka dot"). Also, you may use `Augmented Images` feature to quickly get ARAnchors with a help of image detection algorithm.

### Conclusion

**Plane Detection is a very fast stage in case you're using LiDAR or iToF sensors**. But for devices without LiDAR or iToF (when you're using ARKit 3.0 and lower or ARCore 1.17 and lower) there will be some delay at plane detection stage.

If you need more details about LiDAR scanner, read [my story](https://medium.com/macoclock/arkit-911-scene-reconstruction-with-a-lidar-scanner-57ff0a8b247e) on Medium.

Comment: Thanks much.   It sounds like by the time I get something complete the technology will probably be better, so I'll work around that for now.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an info about new Google's API.